# CSS Grid Template: Fill columns depending on cell’s class

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a simple grid layout where cells can be 100% or 50% wide. Some cells have a `.left` or `.right` class. Whatever the order of those cells in my HTML tree, is it possible to append it either to the right or left side, depending on their class, until a new full width cell is set?
[image]

The code I used so far:

```
main{
  display:grid;
  grid-template:"top top" "left right";
}
section{
  grid-area:top;
}
section.left{
  grid-area:left;
}
section.right{
  grid-area:right;
}
```

Edit: @wuppie367’s answer solves perfectly my problem, here is how this can be done: https://jsfiddle.net/r2myL1bt/

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Comment: @Michael_B I have updated my question.

Comment: Does this work for you?: https://jsfiddle.net/r2myL1bt/

Comment: @wuppie367 Thank you, this is exactly what I am looking for. It also helps me to understand more deeply CSS grid thanks!

Comment: @rooofl No problem. Posted the answer below. I would appreciate it if you accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it like this. The elements on the right will fill the gaps between the wide elements, so only the order of the wide and left elements matter. The elements on the right will fill the gaps from top to bottom.

```css
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  width: 240px;
}

.main div {
  margin: 10px;
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
}

.main .wide {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  background-color: green;
}

.main .left {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: auto;
  background-color: red;
}

.main .right {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="wide"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>

  <div class="wide"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add this css to the classes and if they're both 50% width with no margin or padding, or combined with those make 50% they should sit correctly.

```
.left{
float:left;
}
.right{
float:right;
}
```